# Qtimer and system clock changes

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application which uses QTimers. The problem here is, when user adjusts the system clock, this is upsetting the timers and other date and time related calculations. Is QElapsedTimer any better? The problem with this elapsed timer is, it's not a QObject; thus, no signals and slots, which makes tracking timeouts impossible. The target OS is win XP.
Could someone please suggest some sensible solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you doing with the timers?

Comment: @neagoegab They are mainly used for calculating and using time duration. Thanks

Comment: If QTimer implementation is based on WINAPI SetTimer, changing system clock will not trigger your timer... maybe you have other issues. Also, a application that has date & time based calculation should take care of date & time changes... Can you post a code example?